# to_sql out of memory error for string (object) data

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am using to_sql to write a pandas dataframe to a SQL server database. The dataframe is tiny (1 column, 100 rows). However, I am getting the error:

```
 cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
 MemoryError
```

The dataType of the column is object (i.e. string). If I convert the dataType to INT, then the code executes without an error.

Why does object data cause an out of memory error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Python dtype object is *not* the same as string. Does `dtype()` return "object"? You said that your data has one column - is it stored as a numpy array or a DataFrame? If it *is* truly a DataFrame, use `df.dtypes` to see the data type for each column (not the dtype of the entire DataFrame, which is an object). If the column is an object, then you are trying to pass each record as a Python object - so the data structure is not really "tiny" at all. In that case, converting to float or string would work just as well as converting to int.